# how to restore database to particular folder?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i have DB Backfile in

> D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\Sample.bak

When i restore it will restore to

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS2012\MSSQL\DATA

this directory. But i want to restore to

> D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\TestDB\

How can i do?
i used the following query

> RESTORE DATABASE backup_lookup  FROM DISK =
>   'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\Sample.bak.'

Please help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try following command.

```
RESTORE DATABASE backup_lookup FROM DISK = 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\Sample.bak' 
WITH REPLACE, 
MOVE 'backup_lookup_DATA' TO 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\TestDB\backup_lookup.mdf', 
MOVE 'backup_lookup_LOG' TO 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\TestDB\backup_lookup_1.ldf'
```

Comment: ya.. But my Backupname file name is Sample. That is not DB name. . i dont know that what is DB name

Answer (score 0):

As you can try this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Sample FROM DISK = 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\Sample.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Sample_Data' TO 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\TestDB\Sample_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'Sample_Log' TO 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\TestDB\Sample_Log.ldf',
NORECOVERY
GO
RESTORE LOG Sample FROM DISK = 'D:\Prabhagar\Projects\ZIP\Priya DB\Backups\TestDB\Sample.TRN'
GO
```